# What distribution is CirrOS based on?

Tags: openstack

What distribution is [CirrOS](https://launchpad.net/cirros) based on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it is an entirely custom-built Linux distribution, it's not based on an existing distro.

Answer (score 41):

cirros currently uses [buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) to build the image.  The build process is documented in the [README](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~smoser/cirros/trunk/view/head:/README) of the cirros source code ([lp:cirros](http://code.launchpad.net/cirros)).

For a kernel, cirros simply re-uses the latest Ubuntu 12.04 kernel at the time of the cirros release.  Future versions of cirros are likely to use 14.04 kernels.  Re-using a kernel simply means I don't have to deal with building/patching/configuring my own.